# Blender 2.8 - How to access material nodes?

Tags: materials, compositing-nodes

In Blender 2.7 we could change material nodes in composting. They removed it in Blender 2.8, where can I find it??

[image]

Comment: Hi, you mean shading in the main menus on top? Right where you have all the workspaces you need. Layout, modeling, sculpting, UV editing, Texture paint, Shading....

Comment: Oh ok, they created a new section called "Shader Editor". Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in 2.8 the shader editor and the compositor have been split into two different editors.

You can use nodes in shading tab or if you go to compositing tab then enable the "Use Nodes" which you can see in the image:[image]

Comment: If I click `Use nodes` in composting tab, then I just see the nodes from the composting not from the material.

Comment: What about the shading tab?