# Need to add Shader node to this tree but it's not available

Tags: node-editor, shaders

I'm trying to add the "Shader" node to this drop-down menu but it's not available and I truly don't know how to figure it out or even find it otherwise lmao.  I promise I tried Googling first for about an hour, then just clicking around for an hour, but I'm stuck because I'm super-new to using Blender (I've managed to do very little in the two weeks since I started trying to learn) and tbf my ADHD is bad and it's making me feel hella stupid so I just need a kind soul to tell me exactly what to do.

If it helps at all, I'm trying to make this object glossy and I'm following a Youtube tutorial to learn how to do that.  I had this problem with 2.70 and just updated to 2.80 because I figured some of you might tell me to update, but the issue persists!  And tbf (again), it seems that I might have trouble following tutorials now because 2.80 looks so different from 2.70!  Haha!

Here's a screengrab of what happened when I pressed Shift + A in 2.70 (very similar to 2.80).

[image: Shift + A]

Here's a screengrab of what happened when I tried to search for "Shader" within that search function in 2.70.

[image: Searching for "shader" yields no results]

And here's what happens when I try to search for "shader" in the search bar in 2.80 (literally the same as in 2.70; I don't know why I thought updating would fix this.  I feel so stupid right now!)

[image]

Sorry & thanks in advance.  I'll answer whatever questions you have to the best of my ability, but I'm apparently an idiot so I may not know how to find what you're asking me for and anyway I'm assuming this'll be as simple as a few clicks or keystrokes.  I really appreciate it!!

EDIT:  Whoever closed this question, the link provided uses v2.70 and I'm using 2.80 so everything looks completely different and I'm a complete beginner so I don't know what they're telling me to click!  So it doesn't help me at all!  I'm really frustrated and would appreciate it if you'd tell me how to do that in 2.80!  :^)

Comment: If you're still there, you're in the COMPOSITING tab, you want to be in the SHADING tab. If you go there and the graph is blank, hit the plus button in the center to give your object a material and adjust the values on the Principled BSDF. Lowering the roughness will make it glossy. I have a picture, but I can't post it because the question is closed.

Comment: You are in the wrong editor, the image you show is for the compositor, you need the shader editor. read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180803/blender-2-8-how-to-access-material-nodes/180804#180804

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Blender 2.8 - How to access material nodes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/180803/blender-2-8-how-to-access-material-nodes)